# Protect Urls's in Asp.net mvc 3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I am working on a application in which A Junior user has Edit access on a normal data item and does not have edit access on a banned data item. The URL to edit the data item looks like this:

```
http://localhost/App/Items/Edit?id=5
```

The problem is if the junior user knows the Id of a banned item, he can easily change the id in the URL and edit that item.
How do I prevent that?

Comment: You should validate that on the server side. Either a filter on a query or a code in code-behind (c#) where you check the user's credentials (roles and/or rights) against the data being queried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution like this:**

```
public class ItemAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute{

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext){
        var userRepository = Container.Get<IRepository<User>>();
        var userName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.GetOnlyUserName();
        var user = userRepository.GetBy(u => u.Name == userName && u.IsEnabled).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null) return false;
        user.Identity = httpContext.User.Identity;
        httpContext.User = user;
        ItemId = httpContext.Request["id"].ToInt();
        var itemRepository = Container.Get<IItemRepository>();
        var item = itemRepository .Get(ItemId );
        var currentUser = Container.Get<CurrentUser>();
        currentUser.user = user;
        var isUserPermitted = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (isUserPermitted)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (item!= null)
        {
            if (!item.IsBanned)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } 
}


 protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
       // Unauthorize request URL
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent a user for changing the URL. What you can do is check their permissions, and validate the request, for executing whatever action it is they're requesting. Check out this [blog entry](http://idunno.org/archive/2011/06/18/so-what-went-wrong-with-citibank.aspx) by Barry Dorrans that discusses this sort of scenario.

Comment: link seems to be down